# How to parse csv file with newlines in a field? (Text::CSV)?

Tags: perl, csv

I use the following script to parse a csv file.

http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~kinzler/home/binp/csv2tsv

But if there are newlines in a field, it will not work. Is there a robust way to parse fields with newlines in them?

```
$ cat main.csv
a,"1
  2
 3
"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module. Fields with embedded newlines are discussed [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#Embedded-newlines)